# The usage of ... number(s) of

Tags: word-usage, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, count

Here we wish to make sure the usage of ... number(s) of ..., which one below is correct?

---

An even number of people

An even number of cards

Even numbers of people

Even numbers of cards

---

An odd number of people

An odd number of cards

Odd numbers of people

Odd numbers of cards

---

Six numbers of people

Six numbers of cards

Six number of people

Six number of cards

A six number of people

A six number of cards

Comment: All combinations with _six number_ are ungrammatical; _six_ **is** a number, so it doesn't need a label, just like we don't say _Bill person._ The singulars with _even_ and _odd_ are all grammatical, but the plurals are problematical; _odd numbers of cards_ must refer to at least two collections of cards, each of which contains only an odd number of cards. This is not your ordinary situation, though there's nothing ungrammatical about them -- only a bizarre meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the first group are valid in appropriate context e.g.

> There are an even number of people in the room
>
> There are an even number of cards on the table
>
> We have even numbers of people on each team
>
> Each player has even numbers of cards

Similarly for the second group.

As for the last group, I can't think of an example where any of them make sense.

Comment: Though _We have an even number of people on each team_ is also grammatical, and in my idiolect at least, more natural. And similarly for the other cases.

Comment: Indeed, I would find that as palatable as the examples I proposed.